# unable to start mysql as a service

Tags: mysql

I have successfully installed the MySQL server version 8.0.25 using the apt method on debian 10 machine and the command at `mysql --version` is giving me the version `mysql  Ver 8.0.25 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`, however, when I try to start the service using the command `service mysql restart` it is giving me the error as `mysql: unrecognized service`. The same error is shown for MySQL service as well `mysqld: unrecognized service`. Please help